# Excel VBA solver loop - How can I flag rows where solver could not find a feasible solution

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, solver

I'm using VBA to loop through several hundred rows with `Objective` cells to be minimized using Solver.

Solver often isn't able to find a solution, but provides nothing to indicate whether the `Objective` cell has legitimately been minimized or whether solver quit prematurely because it could not find a feasible solution.

I am using `SolverSolve UserFinish:=True` and `SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1` to avoid clicking through hundreds of dialogue boxes.

Ideally, I would like to be able to return some sort of a flag beside the `Objective` cell to indicate whether solver was able to find a solution.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
For i = iStart To iStop

'clear solver
    SolverReset

'set up formula
    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("$EN$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        Range("$U$4:$AE$4,$BX$4:$CI$4,$CJ$4:$CU$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

'set parameters

    'set variables as integers

        'number of each model
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$U$4:$AE$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
            Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        'mono allocations
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BX$4:$CI$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
            Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        'colour allocations
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$CJ$4:$CU$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
            Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"

    'set mono/colour max >= Optimal mono/colour click allocation
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$EI$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
            Relation:=3, FormulaText:=Range("$EK$4").Offset(i, 0).Address

    'set colour max >= Optimal total colour click allocation
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$EJ$4").Offset(i, 0).Address, _
            Relation:=3, FormulaText:=Range("$EM$4").Offset(i, 0).Address

'solve and avoid popups
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `SolverSolve` returns a result you can use to determine the outcome

From MSDN:

> If a Solver problem has not been completely defined, SolverSolve returns the #N/A error value. Otherwise the Solver runs, and SolverSolve returns an integer value corresponding to the message that appears in the Solver Results dialog box:
>
> **0** = Solver found a solution. All constraints and optimality conditions are satisfied.
> **1** = Solver has converged to the current solution. All constraints are satisfied.
> **2** = Solver cannot improve the current solution. All constraints are satisfied.
> **3** = Stop chosen when the maximum iteration limit was reached.
> **4** = The Objective Cell values do not converge.
> **5** = Solver could not find a feasible solution.
> **6** = Solver stopped at user's request.
> **7** = The  linearity  conditions  required by this LP Solver are not satisfied.
> **8** = The problem is too large for Solver to handle.
> **9** = Solver encountered an error value in a target or constraint cell.
> **10** = Stop chosen when the maximum time limit was reached.
> **11** = There is not enough memory available to solve the problem.
> **13** = Error in model. Please verify that all cells and constraints are valid.
> **14** = Solver found an integer solution within tolerance. All constraints are satisfied.
> **15** = Stop chosen when the maximum number of feasible [integer] solutions was reached.
> **16** = Stop chosen when the maximum number of feasible [integer] subproblems was reached.
> **17** = Solver converged in probability to a global solution.
> **18** = All variables must have both upper and lower bounds.
> **19** = Variable bounds conflict in binary or alldifferent constraint.
> **20** = Lower and upper bounds on variables allow no feasible solution.

You can use this to determine the success or otherwise of the Solve, and then write a flag to the sheet as required

Refer [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/solversolve-function)

Comment: Thanks Chris.I saw the MSDN article, but couldn't figure out how to paste the result of the `SolverSolve` function into a given cell in each row that I'd like to iterate through.

I even tried pasting the MSDN code verbatim, but didn't see the message boxes that I assumed would pop up.

Any additional guidance you could provide would be beneficial.

Comment: `Range("$ZZ$4").Offset(i, 0) = SllverSolve(UserFinish:=True)`